# Show multiple markers(100m) in Google map for Android

Tags: android

I am able to show multiple markers in the map but if the locations are very nearby(near about 100 mts) then my markers are overlapping, I want to show the markers even if the distance between two locations are near about 100mts. I am using Google API V2. Can anyone guide me on this

Comment: when you zoom in only then you see the markers well, am I right?

Comment: Yes, I tried that even when I zoomed to max. also I could not be able to see still its overlapping. Is there any other alternate way to nearby markers.?

Comment: Let me explain more clear about my issue,
Let's say I am at particular position there i tried to fetch the current location of mine and shown in map with marker,
after that I have walked 100 meters again from there tried to fetch my current location and shown in map with marker.
In the above two scenarios, the marker is pointing to same location and they are overlapping even if zoom at max level also still they are overlapped. Usually it should not overlap right because there is difference between two location is 100meters. How can I show accurately those markers in the map without overlapping

Comment: I was thinking about having flat and very small markers like dots